# Giving Role to LDAP Authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am using ASP.NET MVC and LDAP as authentication. It was successful. but I don't have any idea about how to give roles to the users. for example, I can login via LDAP with username "xxxx", and I want to give that "xxxx" role as "admin". then I can control the view with [Authorize(Roles="admin")].
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP users are generally assigned roles in the directory they are hosted in.

You would be giving control over the user capabilities to the administrators of your LDAP service.  Which is fine but might not be what you want.

You could also add you own roles in your AspNet application and rely on the LDAP service for authentication only while storing your own roles in your application.